# Java Threading in my Connect 4 game

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

Okay, so I'm working on a Connect 4 game for my Java class and this is what I have so far. I'm trying to get the sleep thread method to work(at the bottom) but I'm not sure how to get it to only call the first one for the first click and the second one for the second click and so on.

Any help or input is appreciated

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.*;

public class ConnectMain  extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
private JButton btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7;
private JButton Reset;
private JTextField[][] text;
private char myLabel;
private Moving mover;

public ConnectMain() {

    this.setLayout(null);
    this.setBounds(400,300, 600, 600);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.cyan);

    text = new JTextField [7][6]; 
    for (int a = 0 ; a < 7; a++) 
    {

        for (int b = 0; b < 6; b++) 
        {

            text[a][b] = new JTextField();
            add(text[a][b]);
            text[a][b].setBounds(50 + (a*70), (b+3) * 50 , 50, 50);
            text[a][b].addActionListener(this);

            Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 20);
            text[a][b].setFont(font);
            text[a][b].setHorizontalAlignmen(JFormattedTextField.CENTER);

            text[a][b].setForeground(Color.red); 



        }


    }       

        mover = new Moving(text);

        btn1 = new JButton();
        add(btn1);
        btn1.setBounds(50, 50, 50, 50);
        btn1.addActionListener(this);


        btn2 = new JButton();
        add(btn2);
        btn2.setBounds(120, 50, 50, 50);
        btn2.addActionListener(this);


        btn3 = new JButton();
        add(btn3);
        btn3.setBounds(190, 50, 50, 50);
        btn3.addActionListener(this);

        btn4 = new JButton();
        add(btn4);
        btn4.setBounds(260, 50, 50, 50);
        btn4.addActionListener(this);

        btn5 = new JButton();
        add(btn5);
        btn5.setBounds(330, 50, 50, 50);
        btn5.addActionListener(this);

        btn6 = new JButton();
        add(btn6);
        btn6.setBounds(400, 50, 50, 50);
        btn6.addActionListener(this);

        btn7 = new JButton();
        add(btn7);
        btn7.setBounds(470, 50, 50, 50);
        btn7.addActionListener(this);


        Reset = new JButton("Reset");
        add(Reset);
        Reset.setBounds(200, 470, 150, 50);
        Reset.addActionListener(this);


}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ConnectMain();
}
int space1 = 5;
int space2 = 5;
int space3 = 5;
int space4 = 5;
int space5 = 5;
int space6 = 5;
int space7 = 5;

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    if (myLabel == 'X') { 
                    myLabel = 'O'; 
                } 
                else { 
                    myLabel = 'X'; 
                } 



        if (e.getSource() == btn1)
        {
            mover.start();
            text[0][space1].setText("" + myLabel);

            space1--;



    }
        if (space1 == -1)
        {
            btn1.setEnabled(false);


        }
    {
     if (e.getSource() == btn2)     
    {
            text[1][space2].setText("" + myLabel);

            space2--;

        } 
        if (space2 == -1)
        {
            btn2.setEnabled(false);
        }

     if (e.getSource() == btn3)     
    {
            text[2][space3].setText("" + myLabel);

            space3--;

        } 
        if (space3 == -1)
        {
            btn3.setEnabled(false);
        }

     if (e.getSource() == btn4)     
    {
            text[3][space4].setText("" + myLabel);

            space4--;

        } 
        if (space4 == -1)
        {
            btn4.setEnabled(false);
        }

    if (e.getSource() == btn5)      
    {
            text[4][space5].setText("" + myLabel);

            space5--;

        } 
    if (space5 == -1)
    {
        btn5.setEnabled(false);
    }

    if (e.getSource() == btn6)      
    {
            text[5][space6].setText("" + myLabel);

            space6--;

        } 
    if (space6 == -1)
    {
        btn6.setEnabled(false);
    }

    if (e.getSource() == btn7)      
    {
            text[6][space7].setText("" + myLabel);

            space7--;



        } 
    if (space7 == -1)
            {
                btn7.setEnabled(false);
            }

}
       if (e.getSource() == Reset)  
       {
           this.dispose();
           new ConnectMain();
       }

}


public class Moving extends Thread {
    JTextField text[][];
    public Moving(JTextField text[][])
    {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public void run () {
        for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
            text[0][y].setText("" + myLabel);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }   
            text[0][y].setText("");



        }


        for (int y=0; y < 4; y++) {
            text[0][y].setText("" + myLabel);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }   
            text[0][y].setText("");


            /*
        }
        for (int y=0; y < 3; y++) {
            text[0][y].setText("" + myLabel);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }   
            text[0][y].setText("");


        }
        for (int y = 0; y < 2; y++) {
            text[0][y].setText("" + myLabel);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }   
            text[0][y].setText("");


        }
        for (int y=0; y < 1; y++) {
            text[0][y].setText("" + myLabel);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }   
            text[0][y].setText("");


        }
        */}
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, as you've never told us what effect you're trying to achieve, but I suspect that you want to use a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead of a background Thread. So please do tell us what this "sleep Thread method" is supposed to be doing since the details matter. As an aside, you'll almost never want to create a class that extends Thread, one that implements Runnable, sure, but that extends Thread, almost never.

Comment: Swing is NOT thread safe, you should not be modifying the UI from outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).  I second Hovercraft's suggetions

Comment: I probably have the terminology wrong. What I want to do is make it so that when I press the button at the top, the X appears in the upper most row and descends to the bottom. I can make it do that much, but I get an error after the first button press and it stops working. How do I make it so that it continues to work with each button press?

Comment: Then what you're trying to do is to create a simple animation for your Swing GUI, and for these, it is best and safest if you use a Swing Timer and not a background thread. Please check out the link in my first comment and give it a try.

Comment: One of the objectives for the assignment is to use Thread, so I think I would have to use that instead of a Timer

Comment: Then if you must use Thread, then use a class that implements `Runnable` and that does not extend `Thread`. In your Runnable, be sure to update Swing components on the Swing event thread by using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {...});` Read [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more on this.

Comment: Your example contains an awful lot of redundancy (i.e., lines of code and blocks of code that look like other lines/blocks of code).  That's a sign that you should be working through some tutorials on how to use the java.util.Collection family of classes before you attempt whatever it is that you're trying to do here.  (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)

Comment: Re "...object...is to use Thread",  There are two reasons to make a thread.  (A) to _wait_ for _events_, or (B) to fully use the power a multi-processor computer.  This program does not need that kind of compute power, and your instructor should know that Swing already provides an Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) that takes care of most of the waiting for events (including timed events) that any GUI program needs to do.  Your instructor is teaching you a bad use-case for Swing, and may be teaching you about Threads before you are ready to learn.  (Hint: learn the Collections framework first.)